# Translating a connection string to database.yml file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The problem is fairly simple and straightforward. I have a database `connection string` and I want to make a corresponding `database.yml` file from it.

The connection string is as follows:

```
data source=qsss.gar.de\SQL2012,3000;initial catalog=City;persist security info=True;user id=user_me;password=user_me##2009;
```

Now, the file I created is likewise:

```
development:
    adapter:    sqlserver
    host:       qsss.gar.de\SQL2012,3000
    port:       1433
    database:   City
    username:   user_me
    password:   user_me##2009
```

Now, the problem occurs in line 3: this `qsss.gar.de\SQL2012` is syntax-highlighted, where as the `,3000` part stays white, not highlighted but just as a normal text

Also the problem in last line: `user_me##2009`, it just recognizes `user_me` and then treats `##2009` as the comment, but this part is also a part of the password.

I noticed, if I used quotation marks, the highlighting is OK, but not sure should I use them?

My question is - how should the `database.yml` file look like for the given connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use quotes `"` to wrap the strings.

```
development:
    adapter:    "sqlserver"
    host:       "qsss.gar.de\SQL2012,3000"
    port:       "1433"
    database:   "City"
    username:   "user_me"
    password:   "user_me##2009"
```

This way YML will only interpret these as strings and not as comments and other stuff.

Comment: I tried like you said, but still I get an error saying "found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 3 column 8 (RuntimeError)"

Comment: I think you need to use `host: "gsss.gar.de\\SQL2012,3000"` (Because only one backslash tries to escape the `S`)